# Import Excel Table to SQL Server - with date column

Tags: sql-server, odbc, oledb

I'm trying to import a excel table that has a column with dates. My query works without the column date. I'm using ODBC to import.

```
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
cn.Open strCon
cn.Execute "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MYSERVEREXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=TESTDB].[tbTableTest1] ([opDate], [columnFloat], [columnText]) SELECT t.MY_DATE, t.COL1, t.COL2 FROM [BD$] t"
```

My table:

```
MY_DATE     COL1    COL2
11/26/2012  21,43   MAR
11/26/2012  21,45   GFM
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: As a quick test, create a table where my_date is defined as an integer and try re-importing. If that solves the issue, I have your answer ;)

Comment: i works as i expected. But what i need to do to enter my date as a date. Use format "dd/mm/aaa" or "mm/dd/aaa"

Comment: I always find using Integration services is easier to deal with when importing Excel Files. You may want to give that a try.

Comment: But im using SQL Express 2008 and i need to import it programmatically.

Comment: Try `SELECT CAST(T.MY_DATE  AS DATETIME) AS MY_DATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guys.

I just transformed DATE/Number format to String format.

```
=TEXT(<DATE_COLUMN>;"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 3):

Internally, Excel stores dates as an integer value. I've run into this before and solved it both in SSIS and straight TSQL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085928/reading-in-date-column-if-first-row-isnt-a-date-with-ssis-excel-data-source/9086831#9086831

In your case, you might need to make a computed column that actually applies the formula, assuming you don't have to worry about the 1900 date.

```
-- code approximate as I'm late for a meeting
ALTER TABLE tbTableTest1
ADD opActualDate AS DATEADD(day, opDate - 1,CAST('1899-12-31' AS datetime))
```